# What is an efficient method to inject multiple ads into a page using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, cookies, adsense

Users can choose to turn on ads. It should display ads if it finds a cookie (or not). I've been able to hack together something that seems to work and do what I need, but it is ugly and clunky. Returning the ad code from a function was the only way I could get it to display correctly. What shortcuts can I use to have only one main function that handles multiple ads?

Please take it easy on me since I'm a beginner. Any suggestions or direction would be great. Thanks.

```js
    var showadsornot = getAdCode();
  
    // Put strings in array
  var adText = [
    "<h1>Ad Code 1</h1>",
    "<h1>Ad Code 2</h1>",
    "<h1>Ad Code 3</h1>",
    "<h1>Ad Code 4</h1>"
  ];

  // Look in container to get an array of ad elements
  var container = document.getElementById('globalWrapper');
  var ads = container.querySelectorAll('.displayad');

  // For each element insert the string with the same index
  // (i.e. the first string matches the first element, etc.
  Array.from(ads).forEach(function (displayad, index) {
   displayad.innerHTML = writeAdCode(showadsornot, adText[index]);
  });

  function getAdCode() {
   var showadsornot = "1"; // or empty null
   return showadsornot;
  }

  function writeAdCode(showadsornot, adcode) {
   var newAdCodeTwo = "";
   if(showadsornot){
    newAdCodeTwo += adcode;
   } else {
    newAdCodeTwo += "<h2>No Ads For You!</h2>";
   }
   return newAdCodeTwo;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="globalWrapper">

 <!-- Ad Code #1 -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="displayad"></div>
 </div>

 <!-- Ad Code #2 -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="displayad"></div>
 </div>

 <!-- Ad Code #3 -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="displayad"></div>
 </div>

 <!-- Ad Code #4 -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="displayad"></div>
 </div>
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To start out, notice that `writeAdCodeTwo`, three and four are exactly the same except that one variable is named differently. You could write a function just like `writeAdCodeTwo` that takes 2 arguments - 1 for the ad text and one for the non-ad text. When you call the function just pass in the text that you want for each case.

Comment: Donovan, that was a great idea. Thanks a lot. I should try passing the cookie value the same way. Do you have any other good ideas?

Comment: Usually when you find yourself numbering variables it's a good sign that you could be using arrays. It won't fit in a comment so I'll just write some example code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 4 similar elements and the same number of strings to insert into those elements, using arrays can help.

Say you structure your ad elements in a container like this:

```
<div id="ad-container">
  <div class="ad"></div>
  <div class="ad"></div>
  <div class="ad"></div>
  <div class="ad"></div>
</div>
```

This would allow you to loop over an array of elements and place the matching text inside of it.

```
// First put the strings in an array
var adText = [
  "<ins class='adsbygoogle' style='display:inline-block;width:970px;height:250px' data-ad-client='xx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' data-ad-slot='00000000001'></ins>",
  "<ins class='adsbygoogle' data-ad-format='auto' style='display:block' data-ad-client='xx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' data-ad-slot='00000000002'></ins>",
  "<ins class='adsbygoogle' style='display:inline-block;width:970px;height:250px' data-ad-client='xx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' data-ad-slot='00000000003'></ins>",
  "<ins class='adsbygoogle' style='display:inline-block;width:300px;height:1050px' data-ad-client='xx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' data-ad-slot='00000000004'></ins>"
];

// Look into the container to get an array of ad elements
var container = document.getElementById('ad-container');
var ads = container.querySelectorAll('.ad');

// For each of these ad elements insert the string with the same index
// (i.e. the first string matches the first element and so on    
ads.forEach(function (ad, index) {
  ad.innerHTML = writeAdCode(showadsornot, adText[index]);
});
```

Something else you could do is dynamically add 'ad' elements to an empty container based on the number of ad strings you have in an array. You would simply loop through the array of strings and `forEach` string create an ad element and insert its text.

Comment: The container holding the ad divs would have one id, but you would only need one container to achieve what you have in your example. The 'ad' divs inside wouldn't need an id. You know their parent and what strings you want to apply to them so you just have to have the strings in the order that you want them to be in the 'ad' divs.

Comment: I broke it. My code above is updated. I renamed the class from "ad" to "displayad" because I thought it might be getting confused with "adsby..." The error I'm getting is "ads.forEach is not a function". The container id is the top-most div.

Comment: If you're getting that error try using `Array.from(ads).forEach` instead. You could also use a `for` loop, but `forEach` feels cleaner to me.

Comment: I added html to the snippet so it would run. It no longer generates an error but no results either. I probably have a typo or syntax error in it. It is much better now even without the cleaner array. It is very cool, thanks for helping.

Comment: Ahhh, you know what? `querySelector` should actually be `querySelectorAll`. This way it'll return an array. `querySelector` only returns a single element. That's why `.forEach` didn't work initially. Sorry about that :)

Comment: Also, thanks for updating your code in the snippet. It made it really easy to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: It was my first time using the snippet-thing, very handy. I was wondering how I could demonstrate my project, duh. That was kinda fun. My new script in action is awesome! Thanks a lot for taking the time to teach me a few things.  :)